# 【Xcode6.3.1】ArchiveしてValidateしたらThe app references non-public selectors in Payload/Myapp.app/Myappname:recursiveDescriptionというwarningが出ます

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, app-store

初めてiPhoneのアプリを作成中なのですが、
タイトルのとおりXcodeでArchiveしValidateすると

iTunes Store operation succeeded with a warning.
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/[Myapp].app/[Myappname]:recursiveDescription

というwarningが出てしまいます。

http://qiita.com/PGMY/items/831618ad416780e0dc7c
上記等の記事を参考に何度も試してみたのですが原因がわかりません。。

Project内を「recursiveDescription」で検索しても
検索結果は0でした。

どのような原因が考えられるのでしょうか？
また原因を探り当てる為にはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

どうか宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

CocoaPods等でライブラリを利用している場合は、そのソースに"recursiveDescription"が含まれてないか確認しましょう。

バイナリ(.a, .framework等)をリンクしている場合は一旦外してワーニングが出るか確認しましょう。

いずれにしても、エラーではなくワーニングならばバイナリ段階の審査はまず通ると思うので、それだけが気がかりなら提出してみるといいと思います。

Comment: 有用な回答ありがとうございます！
追加した.aファイルを調べたところ"recursiveDescription"が含まれているのが確認できました！
外せないものでしたので、とりあえずそのまま審査の申請をいたしました。
審査結果が分かり次第、追記したいと思います。